# "NoReverseMatch at /user/" but for an other url path called '"restaurant_detail' with keyword arguments "{'pk'}"

Tags: python, django, django-urls

My page was nearly finished to be ready for an alpha phase but then I got this Error "NoReverseMatch at /user/". This normally means that There is something wrong with the path from the urls.py directing to the page a user was linked to. But in this case I open up the page /user/ and get the error for /restaurant_detail/int:pk. I show you all the details. Don't wonder. HTML elements are in german. : )

The link that was clicked:

```
<a href="{% url 'user' %}">Profil</a>
```

The path in urls.py:

```
path('user/', views.user, name='user'),
```

The path the error is referring to:

```
path('restaurant_detail/<str:pk>/', views.restaurant_detail, name='restaurant_detail'),
path('restaurant_detail/<str:pk>/<int:underpage>', views.restaurant_detail, name='restaurant_detail'),
```

Not part of this problem I think but here is the view of the user page in views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def user(request):
    currentUser = request.user
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(account=request.user)
    liked = Restaurant.objects.filter(likes=currentUser)
    foods = Food.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        #comment_form = CreateCommentForm(request.POST or None)
        userForm = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=currentUser)
        pictureForm = PictureUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                        request.FILES,
                                        instance=currentUser)
        if userForm.is_valid():

            userForm.save()
            pictureForm.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account hast been updated')
            return redirect('user')

    else:
        userForm = UserUpdateForm(instance=currentUser)
        pictureForm = PictureUpdateForm(instance=currentUser)
        #comment_form = CreateCommentForm()

    context = {'user': currentUser, 'userForm': userForm, 'pictureForm': pictureForm, 'comments': comments, 'liked': liked, 'foods': foods}
    return render(request, 'accounts/user.html', context)
```

The HTML reference to the url:

```
<div id="user_saved_display" class="user_options">
    {% for i in liked %}
    <div class='restaurants_block' data-name="restaurant{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
        <div class="restaurants_img">
        {% ifequal i.restaurant_picture None %}
            <img src="{% static 'assets/dashboard-BG.jpg' %}">
        {% else %}
            <img src="{{i.restaurant_picture.url}}">
        {% endifequal %}

        </div>
        <div class="restaurants_name">
            <p><a class="restaurants_name_link" href="{% url 'restaurant_detail' pk=i.pk underpage=0 %}">{{i.name}}</a></p>
        </div>
```

and other html:

```
<div id="user_comments">
        {% for comment in comments reversed %}
            <div class="rd_comment">
            <div class="display_comment">
            <div class="rd_comment_profilepic">
            {% if comment.restaurant.restaurant_picture %}
            <img class="rd_profilepic" src="{{comment.restaurant.restaurant_picture.url}}" alt="Profilbild">
            {% else %}
            <img class="rd_profilepic" src="{% static 'assets/PO_Icon_White_BG.png' %}" alt="Profilbild">
            {% endif %}
            </div>
            <a href="{% url 'restaurant_detail' pk=comment.restaurant.pk underpage=0 %}"><div class="rd_comment_username">{{ comment.restaurant.name }}</div></a>
            <div class="rd_comment_time">{{ comment.date_created }}</div>
            <div class="rd_comment_rating">
            <p> {{ comment.ratings }} </p>
            </div>
            <div class="rd_comment_text">{{ comment.content }}</div>
            </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

The traceback I got from Django

```
NoReverseMatch at /user/
Reverse for 'restaurant_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': '', 'underpage': 0}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['restaurant_detail/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/(?P<underpage>[0-9]+)$', 'restaurant_detail/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/
Django Version: 3.1.5
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'restaurant_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': '', 'underpage': 0}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['restaurant_detail/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/(?P<underpage>[0-9]+)$', 'restaurant_detail/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$']
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py, line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.9.0
Python Path:    
['/Users/lucasfalkowsky/django/PlantyOptions',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pgxnclient-1.3.1-py3.9.egg',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/six-1.15.0-py3.9.egg',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/esptool-3.1.dev0-py3.9.egg']
Server time:    Fri, 05 Feb 2021 12:33:03 +0000
```

I hope my problem is nothing new and someone knows what is going on. Maybe I just looked at this code too long and oversee something important.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to change `path('restaurant_detail/<str:pk>/'...` for `path('restaurant_detail/<int:pk>/'...` or `path('restaurant_detail/<pk>/'...`

Comment: The error means that while rendering the template for user there is a link to `restaurant_detail` which cannot be reversed, add the relevant template.

Comment: Hey Jacek, thank you for the quick answer. I tried that and repeated it right now but the error searching for an Int except a String. You got an other idea?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat hello to you :) , I added the views.py for user and there is no reference. I don't know what should send a return redirect...

Comment: Ok I found a bit of code leading to the adress in the HTML form. I added it to the original Post.

Comment: Hey can you paste a complete traceback.

Comment: Yes a complete traceback would be helpful. Also is this HTML in `accounts/user.html`?

Comment: It is accounts/user.html

Comment: By traceback you mean the error message I get from django?

Comment: @Falko absolutely yes.

Comment: `pk=comment.restaurant.pk` would a comment necessarily have a restaurant or is null possible?

Comment: You guys brought me to the Idea to delete the HTML part where I get the error. So I deleted the <a href="{% url 'restaurant_detail' pk=comment.restaurant.pk underpage=0 %}"><div class="rd_comment_username">{{ comment.restaurant.name }}</div></a> part. It works now. Do you think I can make it work with the hyperreference?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Every comment has a restaurant as foreign key that it is written for. So must be.

Comment: Ok @AbdulAzizBarkat You fixed it for me. You are right. We deleted a model from Restaurants that a comment was refering to. I forgot to set the on_delete on CASCADE. It was still set.Null. Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a number of comments being stuck in the database that had no restaurant assigned to them after the restaurant was deleted. I deleted the remaining comments and added on_delete=CASCADE to the comment class.